# Using same XIB for new/edit action

Tags: iphone

I am making an app which among other things has the oppertunity to add new items or edit(show) existing ones by tapping a row in the tableview. The "detailed" view will be the exactly the same on both actions however with the edit(show) view will ofcourse be in the state of whatever the user has chosen. So my question is, is it bad to use the same XIB for these two viewcontrollers? Or should I make the same view twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would (and do) use the same view controller for edit and add. No reason to duplicate your validation code.